# Application.EnableCancelKey not working

Tags: vba, excel

setting of Application.EnableCancelKey is no longer working for me in Excel 2010, nor in 2013. 
Whenever you try to set EnableCancelKey it always returns 1
Here is a simple bog standard piece of example code
Anyone the same issue? any ideas how to circumvent?

```
Sub trial()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As Variant

    i = Application.EnableCancelKey
    Application.EnableCancelKey = XlEnableCancelKey.xlErrorHandler
    i = Application.EnableCancelKey

    On Error GoTo trap_error

    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = i ' give it something to do
    Next i

    Exit Sub

trap_error:
    If Err = 18 Then
        result = MsgBox("ok got it, am at " & i, vbYesNo)
        If result = vbYes Then
            Resume Next
        End If
    End If
    i = i

End Sub
```

Note that the code above is in a blank workbook with nothing in it but that code. It just doesn't listen to the esc or ctrl+break.

Comment: That works fine for me (Excel 2013). Why don't you open a brand new workbook and paste just that code in and try it. If it works - you have a problem somewhere else in your project.

Comment: Using Office 365. If I step though the code, it behaves as Jan describes. But if I let the code run, it behaves as expected. Not sure if this is new behavior.

Comment: Excel 2010 is the same as @Rich Holton describes. This is actually expected behaviour, because EnableCancelKey is always xlInterrupt (1) when Excel is idle or code is not running, which is the case when you're in Break. "The EnableCancelKey property is always reset to xlInterrupt whenever Microsoft Excel returns to the idle state and there's no code running. To trap or disable cancellation in your procedure, you must explicitly change the EnableCancelKey property every time the procedure is called." [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834623.aspx)

Comment: A few notes: the code above is in a blank workbook with nothing in it but that code. It just doesn't listen to the esc or ctrl+break

Answer (score 0):

This is actually expected behaviour, because EnableCancelKey is always xlInterrupt (1) when Excel is idle or code is not running. When you're in Break mode, your code is by definition not running, there's nothing to cancel, and Excel has to be prepared to parse your next input.

"The EnableCancelKey property is always reset to xlInterrupt whenever Microsoft Excel returns to the idle state and there's no code running. To trap or disable cancellation in your procedure, you must explicitly change the EnableCancelKey property every time the procedure is called." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834623.aspx)

Edited to add: nothing in that bog-standard code actually displays the value of EnableCancelKey. Here is a proper test. Hit Esc while it's running. With xlDisabled, it just keeps running, with xlErrorHandler it breaks the loop (Resume Next), and with xlInterrupt it goes into Debug.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i
    On Error GoTo ErrHndl
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    For i = 1 To 50000
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = Application.EnableCancelKey
    Next
    Debug.Print Application.EnableCancelKey, i

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    For i = 1 To 50000
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = Application.EnableCancelKey
    Next
    Debug.Print Application.EnableCancelKey, i

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    For i = 1 To 50000
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = Application.EnableCancelKey
    Next
    Debug.Print Application.EnableCancelKey, i
    Exit Sub

ErrHndl:
    Debug.Print "Hello Erro"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Test output (I did not interrupt the 3rd cycle):

```
 0             50001 
Hello Erro
 2             6373 
 1             50001
```

Comment: wow answers already - thank you so much.
For me esc nor ctrl break work on the code. I used break points to check the value of the variables. I can't at the mo try your examples as it is ploughing through a few hundred million combinations and I'll have to wait now as  :) ... more in a next post brb

Comment: Hi, all just tried the code of Winterknell above on another machine with Win7 & office 2010. Same problem for me, the code does not react to ESC nor ctrl+break. I changed the code to

            Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = i & "," & Application.EnableCancelKey

so that I can see what the value is without going into breakmode. The value lists as 2 when it goes into the second loop, but when pressing escape the window goes in greyout mode and the code does not reach the Err=18 statement.

Comment: It will never reach the Err=18 statement if you are using my code, because my code does not have an Err=18 statement. That immediately tells me that you are not testing my code but some code of your own devising. (Note also that if your error code is not 18, your code will not resume, since the Resume is within the If.)

Comment: Slip of the pen I meant to say ErrHndl code, and yes I did use your code.

Comment: In that case we have established that there is something different in your Win7/Excel 2010 system to mine. Given that mine and others work as expected, we can set aside a change in EnableCancelKey itself. Do you by chance have a personal addin that you store favourite functions in? Because you noted that my code **did** report value 2 (xlErrorHandler) as being in effect, so your original question us answered, even if the result isn't what you expected.